# Logout issue in facebook from my application using facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework (PHP) in which i am using facebook api to add a facebook profile into my application, facebook profile details are showing correctly but logout facebook from application by using getLogoutUrl() is not working. getLogoutUrl() is returning url for logout with access_token but it is not logging out.

```
$logOutURL = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$logOutURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

How to logout facebook from my application?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url() .'dashboard/logout'));`

In you dashboard controller put this function

```
public function logout() {
    //Destory facebbok session
    setcookie('fbs_'.$this->facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', 'localhost');
    $this->facebook->destroySession();

    //Destory app session
    $this->session->unset_userdata('facebook_user_session'); //custom session if you made then only
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}
```

Try this if not let me know further

Comment: actually in my application you can add multiple facebook profiles by using facebook api but after adding one facebook profile when you try to add another facebook profile it is giving an error. so here i have to logout first facebook user from browser before adding another one.

Comment: so in above code i was trying to logout first facebook user from browser before adding another facebook account into my application.

Comment: simple remove this code `//Destory app session
    $this->session->unset_userdata('facebook_user_session'); //custom session if you made then only
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');`

Comment: No, facebook profile is not logging out from browser.